# Query needs to be refreshed as often as possible, what is the best way to store the data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a query that takes 20-25 minutes to run(lots of sub queries and joins, 1300+ lines)

I've written it as simple as I can. It works fine when its ran once or twice a day, which I am doing now. However the powers that be now wan the data as real time as possible.

what would be the best way to keep the data stored?

store procedure that updates a table so that any data is readily accesible?

Comment: How about improving your query? If you'd create an insert statement to update a table and then just select everything from that, while updating that table once or twice a day, I'm not sure that's quite "realtime". I'd still go with finding ways to improve your query... But if you don't actually want to access realtime data, but access a snapshot of the data in realtime (low latency) then probably it would be best to do as you said, save the data in advance in a single table and then just take it from there into your application.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu working on improving the query also, but the data needs to be as real time as possible.

Comment: Given that you are using sql-server, you should use some of the tools available to determine why the query is slow.  Most likely, the performance can be improved by adding some missing indexes.  For instance, run "Display Estimated Execution Plan" to see if it complains about a missing index.

Comment: How often does the underlying data change? Could you use stored procedures or triggers to update the results (without running the query) whenever the underlying data change?

Comment: define "stored". Do you want a data cache? Create a table with a time stamp for when it was last refreshed, and insert the results of the SP into the table. let all your reporting, or executive data come from that table, so it will be immediate. On a schedule, run the SP to update the data in the table. voila!

Comment: @HABO data can potentially change  a few times an hour.

Comment: @Jeremy Data cache is possibly what i am looking for...working to make the query as fast as i can, then i guess ill try that route.